# FCM and iOS - Message only received when switching to foreground or reopening the app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi stackoverflow community!

I am having some troubles with iOS and FCM: when I start the app the first time, FCM messages are not received. If I

- close the app and open it again or
- switch the app to background and foreground again,

suddenly all messages are received. After that, the app works fine - just the first time does not work properly.
The only thing that helps is downgrading 'FirebaseInstanceID' to '2.0.0'.
The other Firebase Pods are

- Firebase 4.13.0
- FirebaseAnalytics 4.2.0
- FirebaseAuth 4.6.1
- FirebaseCore 4.0.20
- FirebaseCrash 2.0.2
- FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0
- FirebaseMessaging 2.2.0

XCode is Version 9.3 (9E145)

My AppDelegate with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions has

```
FMessaging.messaging().delegate = self
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

FirebaseApp.configure()

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I also have

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

     Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

And I use

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    ...
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
...
}
```

Is this a common behaviour/bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This FCM should be registered to background mode. You should allow it running in background.

1/ Enable Background Mode in your project Capabilities and choose options you use (Background fetch, remote notifications)

2/ In appdelegate:
 - Declare: var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?.
 - Add this into applicationDidEnterBackground

```
  backgroundTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Task", expirationHandler: {
                application.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask!)
                self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the background mode is actually not the problem. As I pointed out, messages are not received in the FOREGROUND mode, and if I switch to background and then to foreground again, FCM messages are received. And after I did that, the FCM messaging works fine.

Comment: I am got exactly your case. And I tried my way and its work fine. I think you should check your deviceToken again, because sometimes the deviceToken is not received from Firebase at first time you installed app => you can not received FCM.